# How do I play Chess in Watch Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

I notice there are chess boards with activity-symbols over them in Watch Dogs.  Great, [I love chess!](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/chess/topusers)  However, it always says "activity locked."

What do I need to do to unlock the chess games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I have seen this is when I've been on a mission. If you visit these games outside of a mission you should be able to play them.

Answer (score 5):

The chess games are available only in free roam. Press Esc and Quit mission in order to enter free roam (while it often seems like you're not on a mission, you often are in a story mission)

P.S some people have reported missions to be unavailable when profiler is in use, so it is recommended to put the phone away if the mission is unavailable.